# using inet_ntoa function in Python

Tags: python

I've recently started to program in python and I'm having some trouble understanding how `inet_nota` and `inet_aton` work in Python. Coming from php/mysql I've always stored ip addresses in the database as long variables. Also the `inet_ntoa` method in mysql receives a long variable as parameter and returns the dotted format of an IP, so I assumed the Python version works in a similar manner. However, it seems Python's `inet_ntoa` needs a 32-bit packed binary format. So, having the IP address stored as `167772160` value, how can I convert it to a 32-bit packed binary value (like `\x7f\x00\x00\x01`) which is needed by `inet_ntoa` method?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Python 3.3+ (or with [this backport](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipaddress) for 2.6 and 2.7), you can simply use [`ipaddress`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress):

```
import ipaddress
addr = str(ipaddress.ip_address(167772160))
assert addr == '10.0.0.0'
```

Alternatively, you can manually pack the value

```
import socket,struct
packed_value = struct.pack('!I', 167772160)
addr = socket.inet_ntoa(packed_value)
assert addr == '10.0.0.0'
```

You might also be interested in [`inet_pton`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.inet_pton).

Comment: I'm using pyjamas for my project and I'm getting: "raise StructError,"argument for i,I,l,L,q,Q,h,H must be integer". I've tried several combinations but nothing seems to work. Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: @tibi3384 That's probably because you have a string of a number. Wrap it in `int`, like this: `struct.pack('!I', int(string_ip_number_variable))`.

Comment: Damn,you're right, should have spotted that! Works perfectly. Guess I'm still used to php where the cast would have been performed automatically :). Cheers

Comment: I strongly dislike python because of things like this.

Comment: @jrwren Updated with a current-day solution. I doubt that *any* language offers a simpler way to solve the problem than that. Note that `ntoa` is a socket function and has nothing to do with Python.

Answer (score 2):

```
from struct import pack

n = pack("!I", 167772160)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a late addition to this thread: if you're using Python 3.3 or above, look at the [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module: it's much more functional than the `socket` equivalents.