# How to return the number in socket.inet_aton?

Tags: python, mysql

There is a function on mysql:

```
select inet_ntoa(4294967295 & '-1136577616');

res = 188.65.51.176
```

How to make a function on python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2.7.3

```
import socket, struct

packed_value = struct.pack('!I', 4294967295 & int('-1136577616'))
addr = socket.inet_ntoa(packed_value)

print addr
```

For Python 3.3+ see [using inet_ntoa function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5217780/1832058)

Comment: How to get back the number of?                                       In [49]: struct.unpack('>L',socket.inet_aton('188.65.51.176'))[0]
Out[49]: 3158389680L

Comment: 4294967295 & int('-1136577616') == 3158389680L . And you can't get better result. You can't reverse `&` (bit AND). 7 & 1 = 1 and 5 & 1 = 1 so different numbers give the same result.

Comment: How to get the result then?

Comment: You can't reverse `&` so you can't get `4294967295` or `-1136577616` from `3158389680L`. See also: [How to reverse bitwise AND (&) in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2566235/1832058)