# Converting a bunch of ip addresses in integer form from a file to normal ipv4

Tags: python, ip, text-files, data-conversion

I have a bunch of ip addresses in this format in a txt file

```
1371860127, 95612789, 1473061794, 783171389, 1373944667, 1394266686, 1452016574, 2507366587, 1545773864, 1592403412, 772144341, 1089333738
```

That I need to for example convert them to 192.168.1.1 etc and also to a txt file but like this

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
```

I tried to hack some pieces of python code for reading a file and converting integer adresses but I sadly failed

Comment: Is each one guaranteed to be in the form xxx.xxx.x.x? Are you sure there aren't any that are xx.xx.xx.xxx,, for example

Comment: give this a try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217732/using-inet-ntoa-function-in-python

Answer (score 0):

you can use excel inbuilt functions here :

1. Select all the ip address
2. Separate the range by using Text to column in Data menu
3. Use delimited with comma option
4. Convert the row into columns by copying the entire row and then paste special it with transpose into columns
5. you will get the list of ip address now you need to add decimals according the format you require